# Calling an object and its method from another object class method

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, methods

I have created some classes/objects for some animations.  I created a class called Navigation(), and another class called Stars(). Each of the classes have their own methods and objects associated with them.  I have created a method within the Navigation() class that attempts to run a method and the object associated to it.  The Navigation class method will not run the Stars method. Again I am not calling a Stars Class method with a Navigation Class Object.  I am trying to call a Stars object's method from within a Navigation Class Method, if that makes sense. I am new to OOP javascript and I am having trouble knowing the terminology for this problem to research it out.  If there are any other discussions,articles, or threads to point me too that would be much appreciated.  Or just a general answer to the problem.

```
//Problem is in the Navigation class method spaceWarp()
function Navigation(selector){//Navigation Class
  this.selector = selector;

this.spaceWarp = function(selector1,selector2,speed1,speed2,speed3,speed4,delay1,delay2){//spaceWarp Method function
    var button = $(selector);
    var starFrame  =$(selector1);
    var frameSpeed = speed1;
    var delay1 = delay1;
    var spaceBK = $(selector2);
    var bkTime = speed2;
    var starSpeed = speed3;
    var delay2 = delay2;
    var stopStarSpeed = speed4;

    button.click(function(){
        starFrame.velocity({'top': '0vh'},frameSpeed);//works
        setTimeout(function () {
           spaceBK.velocity('fadeIn',{duration: bkTime});//works
           stars1.flyingStars(starSpeed);//does not work
           stars2.flyingStars(starSpeed * 1.5);//does not work
           stars3.flyingStars(starSpeed * 2.5);//does not work
        }, delay1);
        setTimeout(function () {
           stars1.stopStars(stopStarSpeed);//does not work
           stars1.stopStars(stopStarSpeed);//does not work
           stars1.stopStars(stopStarSpeed);//does not work
         }, delay2);
    });
};//End spaceWarp Method
}//End Navigation Class

function Stars(selector){//Star Class

this.selector = selector;
this.stopStars = function(speed){//stopStars method
    var object = $(selector);
    object.css('background-position-y', '0vh');
    object.velocity({'background-position-y': '100vh'},speed,'easeOutCubic');
    object.velocity('stop');
};
this.flyingStars = function(speed){
    var self = this;
    var object = $(self.selector);
    var callback = function(){self.flyingStars(speed);};
    object.css('background-position-y', '0vh');
    object.velocity({'background-position-y': '100vh'},speed,'linear',callback);
};
}//End Star Class 
//Initialize objects
var spaceButton = new Navigation('#spaceWarp');
var stars1 = new Stars('#stars1');
var stars2 = new Stars('#stars2');
var stars3 = new Stars('#stars3'); 
//run object
 spaceButton.spaceWarp('#starFrame','#spaceBK','3000','3500','3000','6000','2100','7000');
```

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code missing. For example, what is `$` here? It seems you are somehow mixing DOM operations with your own classes. Lets say `$` finds DOM elements matching the selector, then `$('#stars1')` would find a DOM element with that ID. DOM elements don't have a `flyingStars` method. If you want to refer to the object you created with `var stars1 = new Stars('#stars1');`, then you cannot use DOM selectors for this, since this is not a DOM element. Instead you would pass `stars1` directly to the function.

Comment: Thanks you I just realized that.  I needed to actually pass the object as a parameter. : ) Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of javascript where you are not using it to just paint and moves boxes :)

Coming to your question:

```
//Initialize objects
var spaceButton = new Navigation('#spaceWarp');
var stars1 = new Stars('#stars1');
var stars2 = new Stars('#stars2');
var stars3 = new Stars('#stars3');
```

The initialization of your objects are great, but here is the challenge. How are you making `stars1`, `stars2` and `stars3`available to the spaceButton object? In the scope of that object `stars1`, `stars2` and `stars3`are undefined variables. If your objects are globally available, then check via the this operator.

Access the `starsX`object via `this.starsX`

You would need to update your function with the three references.

```
this.spaceWarp = function(selector1,selector2,speed1,speed2,speed3,speed4,delay1,delay2, stars1, stars2, stars3){//spaceWarp Method function
var button = $(selector);
var starFrame  =$(selector1);
var frameSpeed = speed1;
var delay1 = delay1;
var spaceBK = $(selector2);
var bkTime = speed2;
var starSpeed = speed3;
var delay2 = delay2;
var stopStarSpeed = speed4;
var stars1 = stars1;
var stars2 = stars2;
var stars3 = stars3;

button.click(function(){
    starFrame.velocity({'top': '0vh'},frameSpeed);//works
    setTimeout(function () {
       spaceBK.velocity('fadeIn',{duration: bkTime});//works
       stars1.flyingStars(starSpeed);//does not work
       stars2.flyingStars(starSpeed * 1.5);//does not work but now starsX exists
       stars3.flyingStars(starSpeed * 2.5);//does not work
    }, delay1);
    setTimeout(function () {
       stars1.stopStars(stopStarSpeed);//does not work
       stars1.stopStars(stopStarSpeed);//does not work
       stars1.stopStars(stopStarSpeed);//does not work
     }, delay2);
});
};//End spaceWarp Method
```

And invoke the function by passing the references of your `starsX` objects

`spaceButton.spaceWarp('#starFrame','#spaceBK','3000','3500','3000','6000','2100','7000', stars1, stars2, stars3);`

Comment: Thank you thank you! Your example really helped me.  I didn't realize you had to actually pass the object as a parameter.  Scope really gets me sometimes especially in OOP.  It works perfect now!